# How to change Salesforce User Interface theme?

Tags: user-management, user-interface, userinfo

How can I change Salesforce User Interface theme? Specifically I want to change the value returned by the `UserInfo.getUiTheme()` method. There doesn't seem to be a corresponding field on the [`User`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_user.htm) object.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Seems like you want to switch between classic and lightning UI, it can be managed by profiles.

Comment: I got to know that there is UserInfo class and then there is a method called 'getUiTheme()'. here is the link https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_userinfo.htm So i want to try different themes listed in my dev org :)

Comment: I think, you need to create html component on your home page to set it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, `getUITheme` only returns the user's *preferred* theme. What you are looking for is `getUIThemeDisplayed`, which returns the active theme. See here: [UserInfo Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_userinfo.htm)

Now, if you look at that link, there are many different themes, including obsolete interfaces. There is no way to programmatically switch between these themes. If you want to switch from classic to SF1 theme, log in on a mobile device. If you want to switch from classic to lightning, you can switch by clicking on your name in the top right -> switch to lightning experience. This is, of course, assuming lightning is enabled in your org. For more information on enabling lightning, see this: [Enable Lightning Experience](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=lex_enable_intro.htm&language=en_US&type=0)

Comment: There is no way to programmatically switch between these themes. :(